# What variety of hops grows well in the south eastern US?

Tags: hops, growing-hops

I have plenty of land that is suitable for growing hops; protected from wind, well drained, and receives lots of full sun. I'm not sure what variety would do well in western North Carolina and is worthwhile to grow. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you'll have a hard time with any variety you decide to grow there.  Hops grow best around the 45th parallel and the farther away from that you are, the more problems you'll have.  That said, pick a hardy American variety like Cascade for best results and avoid British or continental varieties.